# Travis-CI test on multiple iOS SDKs

Tags: cocoa-touch, travis-ci, xctool

I'm trying to test a framework on multiple iOS SDKs to make sure it's working on all. But I'm realizing that not all SDKs are available on all of the travis-ci `osx_image`. For example `xcode7` only has `iphonesimulator9.0`.

Is there a way to specify an `osx_image` in a `matrix`? This is what my file looks like right now:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7

env:
  matrix:
    - SDK=iphonesimulator8.1
    - SDK=iphonesimulator8.2
    - SDK=iphonesimulator8.3
    - SDK=iphonesimulator8.4
    - SDK=iphonesimulator9.0

script: 
  - xctool clean test -project KGNColor.xcodeproj -scheme KGNColor -sdk $SDK
```

Comment: Related issue I've filed: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4962

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

https://github.com/realm/jazzy/blob/master/.travis.yml#L12-L17

```
matrix:
 include:
  - osx_image: xcode6.4
    env: TRAVIS_SWIFT_VERSION=1.2
  - osx_image: xcode7.1
    env: TRAVIS_SWIFT_VERSION=2.1
```

The docs for Travis are a little sparse, but I saw this a while back on their twitter feed. https://twitter.com/travisci/status/644930409730580480